# Redirect stdout, but stdout still appears

Tags: c#, process

I'm spawning some child processes with Process.Start. Both my process and the child process are console apps. The stdout from the child process shows up in the parent console window. To avoid this, I redirected stdout, but the output is still appearing. My setup looks like this:

```
        var proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            FileName = filename,
            Arguments = args,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        });
        var stderr = proc.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();
        var stdout = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        var stdin = proc.StandardInput.WriteAsync(stdintext).ContinueWith(something => proc.StandardInput.Close());
        proc.WaitForExit();
        Task.WaitAll(stderr, stdout, stdin);
        // Process output
```

I don't write stdout to my own stdout, but it's still appearing in the parent console. This only seems to occur for some child processes and not others. I don't have the source to the tool being run here. How can I stop this output from occurring?

Comment: What process did you start? Some programs did not write to `stdout` but to console directly.

Comment: Good question. It's an external tool for which I don't have the source, so I have no idea.

Comment: Did you try to run any other program to verify your code? Are their output also printed on parent console or not?

Comment: I do execute other child processes and don't have this problem with them.

Comment: Did you try to run problem tool in standard `cmd` console and use redirecting operators `>` `2>` `<`, does them work?

Comment: `>` and `2>` have absolutely no effect.